# PHP array to URLs?

Tags: php, html

The code below scans a directory, removes '..', '.' and outputs a list of the files in that directory.

```
$dir    = 'MyDirectory/';
$scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));
echo "<ul><li>" . implode("</li><li>", $scanned_directory) . "</li></ul>";
```

Result:

```
<ul>
<li>part1</li>
<li>part2</li>
<li>part3</li>
</ul>
```

How can I have the output be similar to:

```
<ul>
<li><a href='part1'>part1</a></li>
<li><a href='part2'>part2</a></li>
<li><a href='part3'>part3</a></li>
</ul>
```

If the question needs to change or I need to be more descriptive I would be happy to do so. Please just tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with `foreach` instead of `implode`

Comment: and close your `<li>` with `</li>` instead

Comment: Where does the `.html` part come from?

Comment: Ah that was a typo. In the code it is closed with </li>

Comment: Good point jeroen.. I removed that from the question. I just wish to add the link around each result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
echo '<ul>';

foreach ($scanned_directory as $file) {
    echo "<li><a href='" . $file . "'>" . $file . "</a></li>'";
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$urls = array('part1', 'part2', 'part3');

$html = '<ul>';
foreach($urls as $url){
    $html .= "<li><a href='{$url}.html'>{$url}</a></li>";
}
$html .= '</ul>'; 

echo $html;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well Be0wulf.